# Subtracting values from two different Tables with Many To Many Relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I Have two tables,** table1 = products**

| Product | QTY |
| --- | --- |
| Product1 | 20 |
| product2 | 10 |
| product3 | 15 |
| product2 | 10 |
| product1 | 5 |

products table contains same products which are purchased on different date and have different price but same name.

**Table2 : InvoiceItems table**

table 2 contains invoices for above products

**Relationship**

```
class Products extends Model
{
 
    public function soldproducts(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(InvoiceItem::class, 'product_id','id');
    }

}
```

```
class InvoiceItem extends Model
{
   public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Products', 'product_id','id');
    }
}
```

I grouped both tables by their name

```
$table1=   DB::table('products')
        ->groupBy('products.name')
        ->select(DB::raw('products.name, sum(products.qty) as totalqty'))
        ->get();
```

```
$table2 = DB::table('invoice_items')
        ->groupBy('invoice_items.name')
        ->select(DB::raw('invoice_items.name, sum(invoice_items.product_qty) as soldqty')) 
        ->get();
```

Both above query giving desired result but

**I need difference Balance QTy = totalqty - soldqty**

How can I substract these two tables?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you want `QTy = totalqty - soldqty` per product? So you can see howmany of each product are on stock and sold?

Comment: yes true that's what i want